# The identity of a domain and the identity of its field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let D be a domain and let F be its field of fractions. If e is the identity of the domain D and e' is the identity of its field of fractions F, can we say that e=e'?

Would you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with domains and field of fractions:

Lemma. If $G$ and $H$ are groups such that $H \subset G$, then $e_H=e_G$.

Proof. $e_H=e_H * e_G=e_G.$

The answer to your question follows from setting $H=D$ and $G=F$.

Comment: Thank you! So, e' = (e/e)*e=e.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment... what do you mean by $(e/e)$?

Comment: In the context of $D$ and $F$, what is the operation? addition or multiplication?

Comment: You should say how you deduce $\ e_H * e_G = e_G\ \ $

Comment: @CofeeBliss The set of  field of fractions F is the set of all quotients (a/b) such that a is in D and b is a non-zero element of D. The identity e of D can be identified with the quotient (e/e) in F which is the identity of F.